Firebase Crashlytics wrong number of line or invalid number of line
i have an issue in firebase crashlytics, that the crash report shows wrong number of line or there is nothing at that line. attached picture is of report.

as you can see the line it shows is 459, but in code there is nothing on that line except a "}"
i have tried all sorts of thing to figure out the crash but sadly i could not. any help regarding this will be appreciated.
Thanks

The crash seems correct, I guess you're trying to dequeue a cell without registering it.

This is the common problem in Crashlytics. see: Link
Uploading dSYM files might solve the problem.

Archive your project
Go Organizer (under Window) and right click on the last build.
Click "Show in Finder"
Right click on your .archive file and click "Show Package Content"
There is a file named dSYMs. Compress it and upload into the Firebase Crashlytics


it does not tell me that dSYM is missing. still you think i should do it ?

Sometimes, automatic dSYM uploading can cause this issue. To be safe, you can upload it manually.
